# Preview tool loading incorrect image on initial fetch

Tags: facebook-opengraph, preview

When posting an item to one's news feed that [passes muster with the debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fd.pr%2Fi%2FZJqW), the preview retrieves an incorrect preview on the first share and correct previews on subsequent shares.

**Expected:** That the shared link would fetch the `og:image`-specified image for the shared link on the first pass.

**Actual:** The first share retrieves a different image from the page. (Oddly, an image that is only 105x100, not even large enough to meet Facebook's image guidelines), and subsequent shares retrieve the correct image specified in `og:image`. See a screenshot of this in action:

[image]

**Repro Steps:**: Upload an image with a free Droplr account, share the link via a status update and via a comment. [Here is a URL](http://d.pr/i/CfkZ) I have not shared yet at all, but once it is shared, it will begin to render correctly. So there is 1 free repro :)

**Debugging so far:** This seems to fail in similar but different ways with status updates versus comments.

*Status Updates:* If you post an image for the first time as a status update, Facebook hits the following URL: `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/composerx/attachment/link/scraper/?scrape_url=http%253A%252F%252Fd.pr%252Fi%252Fj2k7&composerurihash=2`. The response object keyed as `jsmods.markup[0][1].__html` contains markup with an incorrect image of FB-wrapped safe image url of: `https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fd25ss6wjc6pfq2.cloudfront.net\u00252Fassets\u00252Fdrops\u00252Fstandard\u00252Fpromo-logo-15dd4a0f7b7831e42dd5f976a17d4757.png`. [Here's a visual representation](http://d.pr/i/a4qR).

*Comments:* If you post an image for the first time as a comment, the response's `payload.comments[0].attachment.markup.__html` key comes back with the same FB-wrapped safe image URL mentioned above. [Again, visually](http://d.pr/i/S3Zu).

---

I'd love to hear if anyone has thoughts on how to get around this or anything we might be doing wrong on our end.

Thanks!